# Adobe Air - Update application framework

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I'm building a desktop application with Adobe Air 2.5. I've read that there is a default update framework and it's also possible to design a custom one.

Should I go with the default one or is it better to design a custom one?

Thanks.
Uli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The update framework used by AIR is always the same. I think what you mean is the UI for the updater. This can be customized to fit the look and feel of your application rather than use the default Adobe AIR look.
In [this article](http://thanksmister.com/2009/09/13/custom-air-updater-interface-using-applicationupdater/) it's decribed pretty good and in [this one](http://www.websector.de/blog/2009/09/09/custom-applicationupdaterui-for-using-air-updater-framework-in-flex-4/) it's described as well.

Happy skinning ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The built-in update framework is pretty simple and easy, but it does require a privileged system user to perform the update.